# after a period + an event (After 10 days after purchase)

Tags: prepositions, time

> I purchased a fan. After 10 days, it makes noise.

Can I rephrase the sentence to the following?

> My fan quickly makes noise after 10 days after purchase.

The "after ... after" part seems awkward for me. But I don't know if it's wrong or there is a better way to express a period plus an event.

Also, is the following ok?

> My car quickly goes out of gas within 5 minutes after gas filing.

(I filled gas for my car. I drove it 4 minutes. The dashboard reports the gas is empty, again!)

**Edit:**

It may be a my programmer thinking, but in programming I can write `DatePlus(1776-01-01, 200years)`, it gives me `1976-01-01`.

I'm looking for a constant construct where I can fill in a time period, and a noun or a noun phrase, like this

```
X(purchase, 10days)
X(gas filing, 5minutes)
```

so that I can use "after" or "within" to relate the calculated timestamp and my topic.

Comment: you can remove the first "after" in the first sentence. The second sentence would be phrased as "My car quickly *ran* out of gas within 5 minutes *of* filling the gas tank."

Comment: Additionally, using "quickly" when you are specifying the time interval is somewhat awkward.

Comment: There isn't really a standard phrase like that. Spoken languages are not programming languages ;)

Comment: I agree with @Esther. You're looking for a rigid solution using a flexible tool. If you gave us more examples, we could likely create a reasonable grammatically correct construct. The problem is, the more examples you give us, the more likely you'll include an example that will completely invalidate the construct we gave you. Helping a computer sound like a native language speaker is a ***very*** complicated task.

Comment: @Esther I will take what you said.

Answer (score 1):

English prefers to avoid using words repeatedly in close proximity. I doubt there's an official rule for that, but it makes sentences harder to understand (the mind loses track of what context was intended for a use of the repeated word).  You can smooth out the sentences by placing the time qualifier at the beginning of the sentence.

> After ten days the fan I purchased started making noise.

This sentence implies that the purchase was made ten days prior to the noise. If you require an explicit association, you can try something like this.

> I purchased the fan ten days ago, but now it's making noise.

As with all things involving language, there are at least a dozen ways those sentences can be written. Returning to your examples, your sentence about a car is also improved by placing the time qualifier at the beginning of the sentence.

> Five minutes after filling my car with gas, it's already empty!

But to show you how this isn't a rule, the sentence can also be written like this:

> My car thinks it's empty, but I filled it with gas only five minutes ago!

and...

> My car is empty only five minutes after filling it with gas.

Comment: I agree with your improvements, but I'm looking for something that meets my part of speech. I want a constant construct where I can fill in a time period, and a noun or a noun phrase.